# saber edad en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

estoy intentado saber la edad en años, meses y dias(ej:24 años 2 meses 3 dias) a partir de la fecha de nacimiento como se muestra en la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los valores se dan separados y son numericos, lo que hice fue seleccionar el codigo, concatenar la fecha y luego en el months between pasarlo a date de la siguiente forma

```
select 
codigo,
to_date(ano_nacimiento||'/'||mes_nacimiento||'/'||dia_nacimiento,'yyyy-mm-dd') fecha, 
trunc(months_between(
    sysdate,
    to_date(ano_nacimiento||'-'||mes_nacimiento||'-'||dia_nacimiento, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
)/12) res
from tabla5;
```

obtengo como resultado lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no comprendo porque sale el resultado de esa forma, algo en que me fije es que el resultado pareciera que se dividiera en 2, las 2 primeras en el año(1999 o 2000) y la segunda la edad...se puede mirar que las fechas anteriores del 2000 les pone 19 y las del 2000 el 20;

que estoy haciendo mal?que solucion hay?gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
 months_between(sysdate, fecha) / 12 
from tabla; 

select  
 to_date('25' || '/' || '02' || '/' || '1989','DD/MM/YYYY') fecha,  
 sysdate fechaactual, 
 trunc(months_between(sysdate,to_date('25' || '/' || '02' || ' /' || '1989', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) / 12) edad 
from dual
```

La primera consulta que te pongo es un ejemplo general y la segunda sería tu consulta; el formato que le doy a la fecha es `'DD/MM/YYYY'` que pondría la fecha como **26/10/2020**, el formato que tú tienes te pone la fecha como **octubre 26, 2020**. Puedes probar en https://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler.

Te explico aquí con cadenas fijas, en tu caso sería el nombre del campo.

Ahora bien, ¿qué sucede con una fecha como esta: 25/02/89?
Pues al poner `to_date('25/02/89', 'DD/MM/YYYY)` resulta que el **89** es precisamente el año **89** y al restar el año actual con **89** da **1931**: eso es lo que te está pasando. Para hallar la edad de la persona pues debes encontrar el módulo de la división de **1931/100** y ahora sí te da **31** que es la edad:

```
select  
 to_date('25' || '/' || '02' || '/' || '89','DD/MM/YYYY') fecha,  
 sysdate fechaactual, 
 mod(trunc(months_between(sysdate,to_date('25' || '/' || '02' || ' /' || '89', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))/12), 100 )edad 
from dual
```

Te sigo recomendando que el año tenga **4** **dígitos** a pesar de todo lo que te he explicado.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda pero me dice que el identificador es no valido, viendo esto reemplace el identificador por todo el to_date y me retorna el mismo problema planteado en la pregunta @Japv

Comment: O sea que de las dos formas te da el mismo error? Explicate mejor por favor

Comment: correcto, tanto como lo tengo yo, como la solucion que propones me da error porque retorna 1948,2015, etc

Comment: dame un time pa verificar bien

Comment: vale, no se que suceda pero es como si cuando dice 19-48 el 19 es porque es 1971 y el 48 es la edad que si concuerda..el mismo caso para los del >2000

Comment: paso algo, si dentro de months_between a la fecha le concatenamos 19 sale la edad correcta de las personas nacidas antes del 2000 las del 2000 las toma como si fueran de los 90...months_between(sysdate,to_date(19||ano_nacimiento||'/'||mes_nacimiento||'/'||dia_nacimiento,'yyyy-mm-dd'))/12

Comment: y no te es mejor en tu disenno de la base de datos en vez de tener tres campos para dia, mes y anno tener uno solo de tipo date, asi simplificarias mucho tu codigo, te ahorrarias todas esas concatenaciones, valora esta opcion que es la mas optima, pues las fechas es mejor tratarlas como tal y no como tres numeros independientes

Comment: claramente esa seria la mejor opcion, pero es un ejercicio planteado por un profesor de mi carrera...el chiste es tener que hacer todo eso xd..

Comment: prueba esto nuevo

Comment: lo he probado y si... el problema esta en que al tener el año incompleto genera el error...en el ejemplo que me pasas esta el año completo(1989) y en mi ejercicio dan los años solo los dos ultimos numeros(89)..eso genera que salga 1948 etc etc

Comment: lo que procede es tratar de concatenar 19 para las fechas <2000 y 20 para las>2000 para que se complete el año correctamente..no se me ocurre como hacerlo

Comment: A ver tienes que tener en tu tabla alguna información sobre el siglo pq si en la fecha aparecen los dos últimos dígitos del año pues no se puede hacer nada ya que si en el año solo aparece 89 pues bien puede ser 1989 o 2089 o 1889, o cualquiera que termine en 89,  te recomiendo si puedes que trabajes el año con 4 dígitos, de otra forma debe haber algún dato que te indique el siglo

Comment: En mi país por ejemplo está el carné de identidad, que tiene 11 dígitos los 6 primeros son la fecha de nacimiento 871014 en formato yymmdd y el 7 dígito sería el siglo, si esta en un rango de 0..5 es siglo 20, 6..8 siglo 21, si es 9 siglo 19 a lo mejor tu tienes algún dato donde puedas sacar este siglo

Comment: Socio prueba ahora que ya se resolvio y te explico lo que pasaba

Comment: ey, si sirvio amigo..muchas gracias!espero la explicacion